# No more Lockscreen on Android Emulator, but why?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-virtual-device, lockscreen

I have the following Problem. I created a emulator with the AVD-Manager. I testet a few things on the lockscreen and all was fine.

But at least i started the emulator and it updatet it self. I never seen that before. After that i cant set widgets on the lockscreen. There is no more button ore something else to do that. I also created some new emulators but nothing works.

Please let me know how to handle this. Here are some details from the emulator:

Thanks for any coming help. :)

[image]